# Where/how to place build files in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm just getting started with OpenCV, and I have the following sample .cpp file (from opencv.org):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

    if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
    {
        printf( "No image data \n" );
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Display Image", image );

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

and I have the following CMakeList.cmake file:

```
project(opencvTEST)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

# Project Executable
add_executable (test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I have a Mac (OS 10.6.8), and I've installed OpenCV 2.4.3 with CMake, and I've searched high and low and tried numerous different things to get this test program to compile (I'm using the command line--no IDE), but I get the following compilation error (clearly, due to the `include` statement's not working properly):

```
test.cpp:3:30: error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
test.cpp:5: error: ‘cv’ is not a namespace-name
test.cpp:5: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:9: error: ‘Mat’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:9: error: expected `;' before ‘image’
test.cpp:10: error: ‘image’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:10: error: ‘imread’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:18: error: ‘CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:18: error: ‘namedWindow’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:19: error: ‘imshow’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:21: error: ‘waitKey’ was not declared in this scope
```

I have a folder named `opencv2` in the same directory as `test.cpp`, and `opencv.hpp` is in `opencv2`, so I don't understand why it's not finding it.  Any ideas?

Also, in general, where does OpenCV expect you to put your source (.cpp, etc.) files?

Comment: Quite interesting...I wasn't aware of the difference between `<>` and `""` for `#include` statements. Do you know if there is a downside to copying `opencv` and `opencv2` (the folders with the header files) into the `/usr/include` directory?

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same issue. I ran the same example from opencv tutorial and got the same error

```
error: ‘CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE’ was not declared in this scope
```

I solved this by adding a header:

```
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
```

Answer (score 3):

You forget to add in your CMakeLists.txt

```
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

after find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

Comment: Thanks, just added it before `find_package...`, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: try add after instead of before

Comment: Still not working, sadly. Do you know if there is a certain directory OpenCV expects me to place my source code?

Comment: @MuffinTheMan compiler provide precise issue - no include found. To debug add message("OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR = ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR}") after find_package and see where this var is points to. Perhaps you just need use #include < opencv.hpp > instead of opencv2/opencv.hpp

Comment: It prints out `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR = `

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27443/discussion-between-muffintheman-and-sergey)

Comment: well going to chat (which is now a broken link) isn't helping me or anyone else

Answer (score 1):

I wish I knew exactly what the issue was above, but I can only guess that it had something to do with the fact that I was trying to work with OpenCV 2.4.3 while already having OpenCV 2.4.4 installed (I'm guessing this caused some conflicts).

I got OpenCV 2.4.4 working on my machine by removing OpenCV 2.4.3 (just ran `rm -rf` on the directory that I had placed it in) and uninstalled 2.4.4 (using homebrew: `brew uninstall opencv`).  After taking those steps to clean things up, I ran the following commands (you must have [homebrew](https://brew.sh)):

```
$ brew update #just in case you're missing updates
$ brew tap homebrew/science #skip this if you already have the science formulae
$ brew install opencv #this took about 15 minutes
```

Finally, I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html), and voila, it worked! I chalk this up to working with new software that wasn't intuitive, getting frustrated, and trying 273 different ways to run OpenCV. I guess that all added up to having an install that I didn't know about, which (I think) caused serious issues. Am I the only one who had such a hard time getting OpenCV to work?

Comment: No, you're not the only one :)) ... With only ONE install, I am having similar problems trying this on Fedora. Thinking about using brew on my Mac - good suggestion. So that'll mean I'll have three copies of the opencv stuff - and, like you at the point of the post above, still not know either where opencv really wants the src's :)) ... did you ever figure that out ?  (I'm trying CDT on eclipse and am at retry count 184 --- looks like I have a ways to go to get to 273 attempts.) LOL "The two-hundred-seventy-fourth try is the charm" ?

Comment: Haha, 273 may have been a bit of an exaggeration ;) I wish I could tell you where the src files should be, but my team ended up ditching OpenCV and using MATLAB instead.

Comment: arrrggg... tried brew yesterday ... failed about %73 in :-\ MATLAB eh?  Well sometimes it's better to pay with cash than have open-sourced headaches. If I could afford MATLAB or Wolfram's gig, I'd toss openCV overboard too. Thanks for the reply anyway! Now, where did I leave that case of Excedrin Extra Strength ? ...  Hm

Comment: Looking into why brew failed may be worth it, though. It was more easy for us to move to MATLAB, since we didn't have to pay for the licensing (got it through our University).

Answer (score 0):

There is one more include folder with the path: opencv\build\include. The complete headers are there and you can set OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR to this directory

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything for me, sadly.